# Ubuntu + Cordova + Android, cant run any android apps

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I installed phonegap and android SDK on my ubuntu 16.04 but cant get any android apps to run.

This is totally new project, I've only done:

- cordova create app
- cordova platform add android (runs fine, no errors)

but then I try:

- cordova run android and build fails

  BUILD FAILED

  ```
  Total time: 1.23 secs

  Error: /home/clomez/Documents/mobile/testapp/app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  /home/clomez/Downloads/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/clomez/Downloads/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string


  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  ```

I'm getting pretty desperate since I need this for school next week, and all the answers talk about changing the SDK version in build. I fail to find any of those options in gradel file...

Running with `--stacktrace` gives exactly the same output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNiMx.jpg  - installed Android SDK's and tools

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
I found the answer for my problem,
it seems google dropped 32-bit support way back, and im running 32-bit linux
if you are getting the same error, **roll back to at least android build-tools 23** which resolved the issue.